# Deployment on WebLogic 12.2.1.2.0 fails due to missing Spring boot class

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, maven, weblogic12c

I have a Spring boot application which I developed in STS 3.9.2, initially as a standalone .jar, which I later migrated to WebLogic using the WebLogic Web Service Maven project template. The target runtime is Oracle WebLogic 12.2.1.3 (this was the oldest version still available from Oracle). I am not using any integration with WebLogic, I only want to be able to deploy.

As described by many online tutorials, I have set the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency to `provided`. Here is my dependency list:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

  ...

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xdb6</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I can successfully deploy my application to my local WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 server.

I am now attempting to deploy this applciation as a WAR-file to WebLogic 12.2.1.2.0 (because this is the customer's platform) but it fails with the following error:

```
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2020-02-21 08:20:46.259  INFO 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] n.n.a.d.ChpDataImportApplication         : Starting ChpDataImportApplication on dev-fat6 with PID 22574 (/opt/oracle/product/fusionaim/smartaim/domains/smartaim/servers/chpdataimport/tmp/_WL_user/ChpDataImport/rlk0tm/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar started by oracle in /opt/oracle/product/fusionaim/smartaim/domains/smartaim)
2020-02-21 08:20:46.263  INFO 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] n.n.a.d.ChpDataImportApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-21 08:20:47.110  INFO 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eac9ca9a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-02-21 08:20:47.178  INFO 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2020-02-21 08:20:47.184  INFO 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 898 ms
2020-02-21 08:20:47.420  WARN 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
2020-02-21 08:20:47.430  INFO 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-21 08:20:47.440 ERROR 22574 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1421) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1360) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1341) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1907) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1823) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:750) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) [com.oracle.weblogic.application.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:265) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:481) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:53) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:202) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:52) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:684) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:692) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:341) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:203) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:207) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:129) [com.oracle.weblogic.deploy.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76) [com.bea.core.weblogic.lifecycle.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1262) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-utils.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:332) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:232) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-runlevel.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-runlevel.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:693) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:232) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-runlevel.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-runlevel.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-runlevel.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144) [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-runlevel.jar:na]
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54) [com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:694) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:633) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.<init>(FormContentFilter.java:61) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedFormContentFilter.java:29) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.formContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:161) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
        ... 108 common frames omitted

<Feb 21, 2020, 8:20:47,480 AM UTC> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "ChpDataImport".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:694)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:633)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.<init>(FormContentFilter.java:61)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Class [OrderedFormContentFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/filter/OrderedFormContentFilter.html) is part of the library spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar which is packaged with the WAR-file. The error might be explained by the presence of an older version of this library (this class was introduced in version 2.1.0), but there don't appear to be any spring boot jars available on the WebLogic server that the server might prefer.

As described [here](http://www.freshjavabeans.com/fjb/2015/05/14/override-jars-in-weblogic-libraries-and-use-those-in-your-ear-war/) the server can be instructed to use the packaged jar by deploying the application as an EAR-file using the following weblogic-configuration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_6.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.8/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <!--weblogic-version:12.2.1.3-->
    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.boot.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

But to no avail (the same error persists). Any explanation why this happens or suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are interested I solved this as follows. It is not necessary to create an EAR-file, you can just add the package list to your weblogic.xml file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>ChpDataImport</wls:context-root>

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

The strategy is to deploy, look at the log in case of errors and add the appropriate package to the list until there are no more errors.